# How to crawl the links in list inside a div

Tags: python, html, scrapy, pycharm

Consider this statement:

```
url=hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="product-wrapper product-wrapper-four-tile"]/li/div/div/div/div/div/a').get()
```

Output:

```
'<a href="https://www.michaelkors.com/gemma-large-tri-color-pebbled-leather-tote/_/R-US_30S9LGXT3T?color=1791"><div class="product-image-container"><div><div class="LazyLoad"><img src="data:image/png;base64,...'
```

I need to crawl to the link which  is cascaded inside multiple divs. The above statement correctly gives me the anchor.Since it is a string so I apply regex to it and then yield

```
 WEB_URL_REGEX = r"""(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:com|net|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:com|net)\b/?(?!@)))"""
 listing_url = re.findall(WEB_URL_REGEX, url)[0]
 yield scrapy.Request(listing_url, callback=self.parse_produrls)
```

URL is correctly extracted. However, it is generating the following error:

Traceback:

```
2019-07-15 01:21:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/skirts-shorts/_/N-28en> (referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/women/clothing/dresses/_/N-28ei)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\crawl.py", line 78, in _parse_response
    for requests_or_item in iterate_spider_output(cb_res):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\MK\MK\spiders\MichaelKors.py", line 107, in parse_list
    listing_url = re.findall(WEB_URL_REGEX, url)[0]
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Edit : reason might be that url variable is not string. If I add /text at the end of hxs.xpath(..../text) then the returned list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions here. There is much simple way:

```
def parse_list(self, response):
    for product_url in response.xpath('//ul[@class="product-wrapper product-wrapper-four-tile"]//li[@class="product-name-container"]/a/@href').getall():
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(product_url), callback=self.parse_product)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the values you are getting are not str, so it would be wise to str() them and evaluate the result. Hope that will guide you further with your problem.

`listing_url = str(re.findall(WEB_URL_REGEX, url)[0])`

Comment: what is the output? if its None, it means it isnt able to find any links. Also what exactly are you trying to do. if you are trying to find all the links within this ul, `//ul[@class="product-wrapper product-wrapper-four-tile"]//a` should give that. Iterating over this results and doing a `('@href').extract` would give the href that you can crawl further.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you wannt to get href of all links inside that list?
Then you can use this xpath expression. Or am I missing something?

```
urls=hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="product-wrapper product-wrapper-four-tile"]/li/div/div/div/div/div/a/@href').getall()
```

Comment: I used get() instead of getall() just to test whether it is correctly working or not. I got this as my value for url in my debugger : 'https://www.michaelkors.com/gemma-large-tri-color-pebbled-leather-tote/_/R-US_30S9LGXT3T?color=1791'. However, now, it is giving me an error when I send the request. It says that the url must be str or unicode. Tried converting to str but doesnt work

Comment: but the error you posted above is within your regex not scrapy.Request. Just to narrow down the error can you try to assign your url manually to the variable and yield it to scrapy. If that works ensure that both the extracted url and your manually assigned url are identical